# Relative clause VS present participle

Tags: participle, style, relative-clause

I think that *virum ambulantem video* and *virum qui ambulat vidéo* are grammatically correct and semantically equivalent.

So is there any stylistic reason one should use one rather than the other?

Comment: Hi John, we just had this question last year. See the notice above for the link. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @cmw yes thanks